# ARC memory management issue with system sounds

Tags: xcode, memory, automatic-ref-counting, instruments

I’m playing a system sound using...

```
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",
                      [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],
                      @"/heartbeat.wav"];

    //declare a system sound id
    SystemSoundID soundID4;

    //Get a URL for the sound file
     NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];

    //Use audio sevices to create the sound
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge_retained CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID4);

    //Use audio services to play the sound
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID4);

    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID4);
```

I’m not sure that this is the problem.. but if it run with “analyze” it comes up as a potential leak.  There is clearly some kind of leak going on as the app gets slower and slower as I run it more times in the simulator.  I have found examples for how to deal with this without using arc, but nothing with.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could turn off ARC for this file as a Plan B

Comment: Yea I thought about that... it would cause a major rewriting of things the way I have it set up is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"it comes up as a potential leak".  What is "it"?

Second, you don't analyze a memory leak by observing a program getting slower and slower. In fact, that's not a normal symptom of a memory leak unless you are exhausting physical RAM and causing lots of swapping. You diagnose a leak by actually identifying no-longer-reachable memory using something like the Leaks instrument.

That said, you don't want `__bridge_retained`, you just want `__bridge`. One of the reasons I prefer the `CFBridgingRetain()` and `CFBridgingRelease()` functions rather than the `__bridge_retained` and `__bridge_transfer` casts is that you are much less likely to make such a mistake.  For example, you'd never have written:

```
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(CFBridgingRetain(filePath), &soundID4);
```

First of all, it's obvious that there's no need to retain `filePath` just to pass it to a function.  Second, calling a `CFRetain()`-style function also makes it clear that you have a responsibility to calling a `CFRelease()`-style function to balance it.

Comment: I ran the code under instruments and it seems the total allocated memory doesn’t increase.  After running the code once the transitions slow down though.  Things like the keyboard popping onto the screen... labels loading fades in and out slow.  If its not a memory issue what could that be?

Comment: Not sure. Check if something is hogging the CPU.

Comment: I found out what it was.. it was a mistake, but not sure why it causes that.  I animated the opacity of an image to fade it out, and I ended up doing it twice nearly consecutive.   Now it seems to run smoothly.